# Logger for Unity3d that hooks up nicely with MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, logging, monodevelop

I want to write a central logger class for Unity3d project. Its pretty straight-forward if I were to print the console logs only. I would want it to look something like the following :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

//Consider this class is a Singleton, and is available to all other classes. 
//I'm leaving the generic inheritance from something like Singleton<Logger> for simplicity

public class Logger : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public enum LogLevel
    {
        Verbose,
        Debug,
        Warn,
        Error
    }

    public bool _enableLogs;

    public LogLevel _logLevel;

    public void Log(LogLevel logType, string msg)
    {
        if (!_enableLogs)
            return;

        // some logic to filter out messages below this "_logLevel".

        // Log the msg to console.
        Debug.Log (msg);
    }
}
```

Normally when you double click a log message, it takes you to that line of code in the MonoDevelop file. How can I modify my code so that it links with the line of code producing it, like in a normal logger? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can. Mind, you could write some code that would include the source of the logging action as part of the log (Debug.GetStackTrace() + some regex) but you won't be able to double-click and jump there.

Comment: I wonder how these plugins work then e.g https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11521

Comment: They're editor extensions. Also I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple solution to what you want: compile your logger into a .DLL and include that .DLL in your project. Now, clicking on log messages should take you to the location you want.

I'm not sure why this works, but it's been known to work like that for a long time (we also have a custom logger that works like that).

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same problem and found this solution, if any one land here in the future.

You have to make your custom logger a dll, then when you double click on the message it will take you to the line were you called the custom log, not inside the custom log.

Taken from this answer: http://answers.unity.com/answers/922165/view.html

And to create a dll that uses Unity API, see this https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html and this https://forum.unity.com/threads/compiling-c-scripts-to-dll-files.318803/#post-2068595

Then you can use the classes inside the dll as if they were in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Filter by LogType, parse logs stack trace and switch to editor if source code file found. It is an Editor loaded class, so it works only there of course.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class ExceptionCatcher
{
    private static readonly Regex StackTraceRegex = new Regex(@"\(at (.*):([0-9]+)\)");

    static ExceptionCatcher()
    {
        // Handle logs
        Application.logMessageReceived += OnLogMessageReceived;
    }

    private static void OnLogMessageReceived(string condition, string stackTrace, LogType type)
    {
        // Check if stack trace has file name and line number
        var matches = StackTraceRegex.Matches(stackTrace);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            // Get full path file name or VS will open new window
            string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.dataPath) + "/" + match.Groups[1].Value;
            int lineNumber = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);

            // If file exists
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                // Pause editor
                Debug.Break();

                // Switch to code editor
                UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility.OpenFileAtLineExternal(filePath, lineNumber);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the regular expression? And could you please give reference of where you found it or is it your own observation?

Comment: Have you seen what the stackTrace looks like? Regular expression parse file name and line number from it - line by line. We used loop here because not all file paths we found are available for us (e.g., standard mono source code). Ain't clue for what you ask about "giving reference". To regexp or code? Both wrote myself. Nothing special.

Comment: If you don't understand regexp look here - [Regex demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wgkTIlO_GEZXyCI4)

Comment: It is not what OP wants. This is pausing the editor whenever a log is received. OP wants to override the on log click event inside the editor.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend the Logger from Unity directly, you can find him in the API-Doc:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class MyLogHandler : ILogHandler
{
    public void LogFormat(LogType logType, UnityEngine.Object context, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Debug.unityLogger.logHandler.LogFormat(logType, context, format, args);
    }

    public void LogException(Exception exception, UnityEngine.Object context)
    {
        Debug.unityLogger.LogException(exception, context);
    }
}
```

Or if you want the default Logger from:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug-unityLogger.html

```
public class MyGameClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static string kTAG = "MyGameTag";
    private Logger myLogger;

    void Start()
    {
        myLogger = new Logger(new MyLogHandler());

        myLogger.Log(kTAG, "MyGameClass Start.");
    }
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Logger.html

See also:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MyGameClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static ILogger logger = Debug.unityLogger;
    private static string kTAG = "MyGameTag";

    void MyGameMethod()
    {
        logger.Log(kTAG, "Hello");

        Debug.unityLogger.Log(kTAG, "World");
    }
}
```

You can edit the Log Method in your Logger, so that the types will be saved on differnt Files or you can set an On/Off switch for different LogMessages, if you dont want Info Logs, set an Enum with Log Levels at start of the Logger.

But the concept is basically the same as in C# standard so I would recommend to read a few textes about C# Logger maybe you get an idea from there:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line

Comment: Unfortunately, double-clicking a log generated by this still brings you to `MyLogHandler` instead of the class where the log was called.